# display index with converter not triggered

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have data grid and i bind the displayindex to  the data context (which it doesn't matter). i use a converter that takes a string parameter that combine a field name and a tableID, from that i can extract the order number for that column (from database)
but the converter never fired, i think it because the fallback

here's the xaml line:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Col1" DisplayIndex="{Binding CarID, Converter={StaticResource FieldNameToIndex}, FallbackValue=0, ConverterParameter=Col1-9}">
```

here's the converter class:

```
public class FieldNameToIndex : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] data = parameter.ToString().Split('-');
        if(data.Length == 2)
        {
            long val;
            if (!long.TryParse(data[1], out val))
                return 0;

            using (AmethystEntities db = new AmethystEntities())
            {
                string fieldName = data[0];
                Fields mat = db.Fields.Where(m => m.FieldName == fieldName && val == m.TableID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (mat != null)
                    return (mat.DisplayIndex != null ? mat.DisplayIndex : 0);
            }
        }

        return 0;        
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the binding programmatically *after* the columns have been created:

```
<DataGrid Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="col1" Header="Col1">
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(col1, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty,
        new Binding("CarID") { Source = this, Converter = new FieldNameToIndex(), FallbackValue = 0 });
}
```

The columns get created one after another and by the time the first columns get created there are no other columns in the `Columns` Collection of the `DataGrid` and thus the `DisplayIndex` can only be set to 0.